# Is it Possible to Create multi Single-field indexes in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongoose

Is it valid to create more then 1 Single-field index in mongodb?:

Let's assume I have a collection of products, and in some queries I want to find by **Category** whereas in others I want to find by **date**

Will it be valid to create 2 single-field indexes for that collection?

 **mongoose**:

```
schema.index({ Category:1});
schema.index({ date: 1 });
```

Comment: if your application query pattern is designed like that then its valid to create 2 indexes like that. It helps in covered queries as well where mongodb does not need to scan any documents.

Comment: You can create up to 64 indexes in a collection. However, note that MongoDB typically doesn't use more than one index per query, so if your query touches both fields and using a sort() as well, you'll be better served using a compound index. If you need additional information, please update your question to explain what you need in more details, along with example documents and example queries.